# Highcharts highstock tooltip series order

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When the highcharts tooltip is shared (all series shown in the tooltip), is there a way to set the order in which the series display in the tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Each point is an object in a array called `points`. If you want it in reverse order you can do that via:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

        $.each(this.points.reverse(), function () {
            s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
                this.y + 'm';
        });

        return s;
    },
    shared: true
},
```

If you want to do some other ordering then you need to provide more information.

Comment: Not looking to reverse, but this got me going - Thanks.